# How to create a third sheet from shared data in two other sheets?

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery

I am trying to use two sheets in excel to create a third sheet.

SHEET1 contains AccsessLevels, an AccessLevel can contain any number of Zones. SHEET2 contains the Zones, a Zone can contain any number of Items.
RESULT_SHEET needs to have all of the AccessLevels from SHEET1, but needs to get the Items from each matching Zone entry in SHEET2.

I have tried Power Query, but wasn't able to get it to perform this task. I have a basic knowledge of VBA, but this is above my skill level.

```
SHEET1
| AccessLevels | Z1    | Z2    | Z3    |
| ------------ | ----- | ----- | ----- |
| AccessLevel1 | ZoneA | ZoneB | ZoneC |
| AccessLevel2 | ZoneA | ZoneC |       |
| AccessLevel3 | ZoneB |       |       |
| AccessLevel4 | ZoneA | ZoneD |       |

SHEET2
| Zones | I1    | I2    | I3    |
| ----- | ----- | ----- | ----- |
| ZoneA | ItemA | ItemB |       |
| ZoneB | ItemB | ItemC |       |
| ZoneC | ItemA | ItemD | ItemF |
| ZoneD | ItemE |       |       |

RESULT_SHEET
| AccessLevels | I1    | I2    | I3    | I4    | I5    | I6    |
| ------------ | ----- | ----- | ----- | ----- | ----- | ----- |
| AccessLevel1 | ItemA | ItemB | ItemC | ItemD | ItemF |       |
| AccessLevel2 | ItemA | ItemB |       | ItemD | ItemF |       |
| AccessLevel3 |       | ItemB | ItemC |       |       |       |
| AccessLevel4 | ItemA | ItemB |       |       |       | ItemE |
```

Answer (score 0):

Load the data from sheet2 into powerquery by selecting the range and doing Data .. From table/ranges... [x] my data has headers.    I assume this gets named **Table1**.   Right-click first column and choose Unpivot other columns.  File Close and load to ... only create connection

code for that is

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Zones", type text}, {"i1", type text}, {"i2", type text}, {"i3", type text}}),
#"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", {"Zones"}, "Attribute", "Value")
in #"Unpivoted Other Columns"
```

Load the data from sheet1 into powerquery by selecting the range and doing Data .. From table/ranges... [x] my data has headers.  use sample of code below which you can paste into home .. advanced editor

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table2"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"AccessLevels", type text}, {"z1", type text}, {"z2", type text}, {"z3", type text}}),
#"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", {"AccessLevels"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Unpivoted Other Columns",{"Value"},Table1,{"Zones"},"Table1",JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Expanded Table2" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Table1", {"Attribute", "Value"}, {"Table1.Attribute", "Table1.Value"}),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded Table2",{"Attribute", "Value"}),
#"Removed Duplicates1" = Table.Distinct(#"Removed Columns", {"AccessLevels", "Table1.Value"}),
#"Duplicated Column" = Table.DuplicateColumn(#"Removed Duplicates1", "Table1.Value", "Table1.Value - Copy"),
#"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Duplicated Column",{"Table1.Attribute"}),
#"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Removed Columns1",{{"Table1.Value", Order.Ascending}}),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Sorted Rows", List.Distinct(#"Sorted Rows"[Table1.Value]), "Table1.Value", "Table1.Value - Copy")
in #"Pivoted Column"
```

What it is doing is basically: [1] unpivoting [2] merging the two tables on from the Value to Zone column [3] expanding the attribute and value column [4] removing the extra columns [5] removing duplicates when the multiple zones for the same access level have the same items [6] duplicating the item column to use as column headers [7] re-pivoting using advanced option "dont aggregate"